How to calculate quantum cost?
In the following two papers:

Automatic Synthesis of Reversible Logic Circuit Based on Genetic Algorithm

Particle Swarm Optimization based Circuit Synthesis of Reversible Logic


a comparison benchmark of quantum cost can be seen. From the reference tracing, I found that they may be referring to the calculation method of quantum cost in Elementary gates for quantum computation, but I still don’t understand it?
I would like to ask a few questions:
(1) Is the quantum cost indicator still being used by anyone?
(2) How is it calculated specifically? Could someone provide a concrete example?
(3) Suppose there is a swap gate, may I simply calculate the number of not gates, that is, quantum cost = 3 ?


Absolutely the cost of a circuit is of utmost importance to quantum algorithms, much as it has been, is, and likely always will be for classical computation. The term "logic synthesis" comes from classical (irreversible) computing but quantum computing and classical (reversible) computing are very concerned with the number of logic gates, their depth, their fan-in and fan-out, etc.
The calculation of any particular gate count or depth would be very dependent on the kinds of gates that are permitted. For example, classically I am very interested in reducing my NAND-gate count as that might drive much about the integration complexity of my classical circuit, but I could additionally or alternatively worry about NOR-gate count or XNOR-gate count or AOI-gate count, etc. Similarly, quantumly most people are worried about the Hadamard+CCNOT (Toffoli) count and/or the Clifford+T gate count, etc.
Turning to the particular SWAP gate, if the basis you use to generate your gates does not include a naive SWAP gate then it would be fair to say that this has a gate complexity and depth of three CNOT gates. It looks like in one of the references the basis is {NOT, CNOT, and CCNOT (Toffoli)} gates; but another famous generating set for reversible logic includes {0, 1, SWAP, CSWAP (Fredkin)} gates, in which case your circuit would have complexity of one (there's only a single SWAP gate).
